# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$, solution verification

Tags: proof-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Is my reasoning right? I have $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so I conclude that it's pointwise convergent $f_n \to |x|$, and moreover it's uniformly convergent to $|x|$, because $\left | \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}}- |x| \right | = \frac{1}{n^2 \left ( \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} + |x| \right )} \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$

That's because $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} \to |x|$ and it's decreasing for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore I can make denominator smaller by $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} \leq |x|$, so I'd get in denominator $n^2 2|x|$ and if $|x| > \frac{1}{2}$ then $\frac{1}{n^22|x|} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$, otherwise if $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ then $\frac{1}{n^22|x|} \leq \frac{2|x|}{n^22|x|} = \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Yes, correct. $\quad \quad \quad$

Comment: There is a mistake, note that

$$\frac{1}{n^2 \left ( \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} + |x| \right )} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$ That is: you want to make the denominator as small as possible to bound the fraction above. The maximum happen when $x=0$, hence the above inequality

Comment: The bounds $$\frac{1}{n^2 \left ( \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}} + |x| \right )} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$ and, if $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$, $$\frac{1}{n^22|x|} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$ both fail to hold.

Comment: @Did Right, when $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then $2|x| \leq 1$, so  $\frac{1}{n^2 2|x|} =  \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n2|x|} \leq \frac{1}{n} \to 0$, because $n2|x| \geq 1$ for fixed $n$ and for every $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ without $0$, we can check as a special case that for $x=0$ boundary holds too, daym I did it too fast and got that mistake

Comment: "because n2|x|≥1 for fixed n and for every |x|≤12 without 0" ?? Well, no.

Comment: @Did Damn, right again, then maybe I must've done too big bound somewhere, anyways solution is already posted and I overcomplicated the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to proceed: If $a,b\ge 0,$ then $\sqrt {a+b}-\sqrt a \le \sqrt b.$ Proof: Move $\sqrt a$ to the other side and square. It follows that

$$\sqrt {x^2+1/n^2} -\sqrt {x^2} \le \sqrt {1/n^2} = 1/n.$$